# Calculating the Tension in a rope with two masses and two pulleys

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, forces

Each time I try to solve for the tension, I always get 80N instead of 40N.

I set $T=mg$ and assumed the tension in the horizontal portion of the block was equal to $2T$ becuase there are two masses and two pulleys and got $T = 80N$.

Could someone please try to point out how I might be setting up the problem incorrectly or show how to solve the problem?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Exactly how **are** you setting up the problem, you need to indicate that for any possible help.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/6093/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at just half the diagram initially. If there were a block hanging off the table and not moving it is being pulled down by gravity with 40N, but since it is not moving there must be 40N pulling the other way to cancel it out since F=ma. If you follow that 40N back you see it is coming from the other block.

If there were 80N in the string the blocks would end up being pulled upwards.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your **assumption** that the tension in the horzontal portion of the rope is 2T. It is not.

For a massless rope which is free to move over a pulley, the tension is the same at all points between the ends. So the tension in the middle (horizontal) section is the same as in the side (vertical) sections.

If the tension were greater in the horizontal section, it would pull up the masses on either side.

*Note:* If the pulleys are not accelerating but are free to move, it does not make any difference if they are light or heavy.